# Dynamically generate subcommands with formatted description in clap

Tags: rust

I want to generate subcommands for `clap` based on a `HashMap` content. To do that, I'm iterating over the items to create new `App` instances. The problem is that `App.about()` requires `&str` as an input, and I can't make one that lives long enough from the `format!()` macro.

Here's an example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=37e0ba7b58786cb0b8c63a29ceeb91f3)):

```rust
use clap::App;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("key", "value");
    map.insert("key2", "value2");
    map.insert("key3", "value3");

    let mut app = App::new("Test").version("1.0");

    for (key, value) in map.iter() {
        let about = format!("Value: {}", value);
        app = app.subcommand(App::new(*key)).about(about.as_str());
    }

    app.get_matches();
}
```

Error message:

```rust
error[E0597]: `about` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:52
   |
14 |         app = app.subcommand(App::new(*key)).about(about.as_str());
   |                                                    ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
15 |     }
   |     - `about` dropped here while still borrowed
16 | 
17 |     app.get_matches();
   |     --- borrow later used here
```

How can I pass the formatted string to the `about()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you have an unrelated mistake, which I'll mention just to reduce confusion about code sample correctness. I haven't used `clap` myself, but it looks like this is overwriting the app's `about` repeatedly

```
app = app.subcommand(App::new(*key)).about(about.as_str());
```

and you probably meant

```
app = app.subcommand(App::new(*key).about(about.as_str()));
```

to apply it to the subcommand instead.

---

The problem here is that `App` doesn't want to own the strings, so there needs to be another object that does. One approach would be to construct a map that contains the `format!`ted strings (and thus owns them):

```
    let abouts: HashMap<String, String> = map.iter()
        .map(|(key, value)| (key.to_string(), format!("Value: {}", value)))
        .collect();
    for (key, about) in abouts.iter() {
        app = app.subcommand(App::new(key.as_str()).about(about.as_str()));
    }
```

The map `abouts` must live as long as `app`.

If you're only going to do this once in your program, then you can just leak the memory `format!` allocated:

```
    for (key, value) in map.iter() {
        let about = &*Box::leak(format!("Value: {}", value).into_boxed_str());
        app = app.subcommand(App::new(*key).about(about));
    }
```

If you want to be able to reclaim the memory but don't want to have to deal with constructing a structure like `abouts` above, because your actual problem is more complex, you can use the `typed_arena` crate to provide a place to allocate any number of strings and keep them all alive:

```
use typed_arena::Arena;

...

    let arena = Arena::new();
    for (key, value) in map.iter() {
        let about = arena.alloc(format!("Value: {}", value)).as_str();
        app = app.subcommand(App::new(*key).about(about));
    }
```

Like in the `abouts` solution, you need to keep `arena` around as long as you keep `app` around.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, you're right. I've tried to create an intermediate HashMap with `String` values, but the compiler complains that it doesn't live long enough. How can I set the lifetime for the `abouts` map? I can't see a syntax to do that.

Comment: @Djent You can't “set” a lifetime, because lifetimes are descriptions of what your program is doing, not ways to control it. What you need to do is make sure the variable `abouts` does not go out of scope before the variable `app` does. Or if you need it to be a return value, then you return both in a struct or tuple, not only `app`. Share what you're trying if this still doesn't help.

Comment: [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab3c68d52cc934fe216b0350fd2f857f) is my code sample. For some reason it works on playground, but when I try to execute exactly the same code locally it complains that `abouts` from line 17 doesn't live long enough.

Comment: @Djent There must be some difference. Maybe you changed something you thought didn't matter. Maybe you're not using the same version of `clap` and something about its lifetimes changed. Maybe you're not using the same version of Rust.

Comment: Right, changing `clap` version to the older one helped. Thanks